# webRTC - Correctly using SIP and seeking a Python library

Tags: python, webrtc, sip, rtp, dtls

I am trying to complete a handshake using DTLS and SIP. This website [0] tells me that I need to send a SIP response to the incoming request, that contains my SDP file and fingerprints used to complete a DTLS handshake. I am using a client <--> server model at the moment. The client is requesting a call, and I already have the RTP packets, but I need to send them back to the client when a connection is established. I am have difficulty establishing the connection.

For reference of the DTLS handshake, I have a screenshot of the packets I am referring to that I have found using wireshark during a browser-browser call using a webRTC library. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euglg.jpg

Where can I find a good python library that is used for these purposes?

```
1 ) Setup the DTLS handshake and encrypt my RTP packets to SRTP?
```

[0] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5763

Answer (score 0):

For the actual SRTP encryption/decryption, you can make use of pylibsrtp:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibsrtp

The DTLS handshake (which produces the SRTP master key) is trickier, but 
pyOpenSSL should soon have the necessary bindings to enable the SRTP extension:

https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/pull/734

Once this is available, you will be able to extract generate keying material as:

```
SRTP_KEY_LEN = 16
SRTP_SALT_LEN = 14

def get_srtp_key_salt(src, idx):
    key_start = idx * SRTP_KEY_LEN
    salt_start = 2 * SRTP_KEY_LEN + idx * SRTP_SALT_LEN
    return (
        src[key_start:key_start + SRTP_KEY_LEN] +
        src[salt_start:salt_start + SRTP_SALT_LEN]
    )

material = connection.export_keying_material(
    b'EXTRACTOR-dtls_srtp',
    2 * (SRTP_KEY_LEN + SRTP_SALT_LEN))

if is_server:
    srtp_tx_key = get_srtp_key_salt(material, 1)
    srtp_rx_key = get_srtp_key_salt(material, 0)
else:
    srtp_tx_key = get_srtp_key_salt(material, 0)
    srtp_rx_key = get_srtp_key_salt(material, 1)
```